How to prevent cape piece from merging into character's body using shape keys?
On frame 259 the character's cape piece merges into his body. How do I prevent this from happening using shape keys? Or is there another method I can use? That piece of the cape merges into his body at all times during the animation.
File: https://we.tl/t-L7lBbFlRUy

